# ¿Cómo aplicar una clase desde JavaScript o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo estas dos clases en CSS y son para darle efecto a un botón. ¿Podría llamarla desde JavaScript o jQuery?

```
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OT";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #b3cbe3; color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 41px; margin: -7.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; 
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No puedes *llamar* los estilos css, sino aplicarlos a los elementos html.

Para lograrlo debes de agregarle la clase con el metodo `.addClass(name)` de jquery:

```js
$("#add-class").click(function(){
  $("#target").addClass("onoffswitch-switch");
});

$("#remove-class").click(function(){
  $("#target").removeClass("onoffswitch-switch");
});
```

```css
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OT";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #b3cbe3; color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 41px; margin: -7.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; 
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-class"> Aplicar clase .onoffswitch-switch</button>
<button id="remove-class"> Remover clase .onoffswitch-switch</button>

<br>
<br>
<div>
 <button id="target">hola mundo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: La cuestion es que tengo un boton que hace la animacion con css, y cuando abro una modal con aceptar o cancelar, respondas lo que respondas no termina la animacion , cambia el valor por debajo, pero el estilo se queda igual, por eso queria saber alguna forma de aplicarle un estilo y mover el boton para que hiciera algo

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que diferenciar que los estilos CSS **no son funciones a las cuales llamar**, si no que son, tal y como indica su nombre (Cascading Style Sheets), **personalizaciones (estilos) que puedes aplicar** a los elementos de tu página.

Tanto desde Javascript como desde JQuery puedes aplicar clases a los elementos de tu página. Te dejo un ejemplo de cada uno de ellos.

### Javascript

Podrías acceder a la propiedad `classList` del elemento para obtener una lista de todas las clases que tiene ese elemento. Una vez hayas accedido a la misma, puedes agregar una o varias clases llamando a la función `add` y quitar una o varias clases llamando a la función `remove` para ese elemento concreto.

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var clase1 = document.getElementById("clase1");
var quitarClase1 = document.getElementById("claseQuitar1");

clase1.addEventListener("click", addClase);
quitarClase1.addEventListener("click", quitarClase);

function addClase(){
  boton.classList.add("onoffswitch-switch");
  /* ----------- Otra alternativa -------------*/
  /* boton.className += " onoffswitch-switch"; */  
  /* Tienes que tener en cuenta el espacio entre el inicio del string y la clase */
}

function quitarClase(){
  boton.classList.remove("onoffswitch-switch");
}
```

```css
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OT";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #b3cbe3; color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 41px; margin: -7.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; 
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
```

```html
<button id="clase1">Aplica onoffswitch-switch</button>
<button id="claseQuitar1">Quita clase onoffswitch-switch</button>

<p>
  <button id="boton">Aplícame una clase</button>
</p>
```

### JQuery

Podrías utilizar las funciones `addClass` y `removeClass` directamente sobre la referencia al elemento para agregar o quitar una o varias clases, respectivamente.

```js
$("#clase1").on("click", function(){
  $("#boton").addClass("onoffswitch-switch");
});

$("#claseQuitar1").on("click", function(){
  $("#boton").removeClass("onoffswitch-switch");
});
```

```css
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OT";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #b3cbe3; color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 41px; margin: -7.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; 
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clase1">Aplica onoffswitch-switch</button>
<button id="claseQuitar1">Quita clase onoffswitch-switch</button>

<p>
  <button id="boton">Aplícame una clase</button>
</p>
```

Comment: @Mariano Finalmente he seguido tu consejo. La verdad que tienes razón, es mucho más recomendable `classList` porque es una alternativa más limpia y no tienes que tener en cuenta el espacio anterior ni nada. Y ya de paso he agregado una breve explicación de cada método. Gracias por la sugerencia ;)